# How to load images on page refresh from folder using Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, image, html, page-refresh

I would like to know that On `Page refresh` I would like to `display` more than `40+ images` which are already `existed` in my `server folder` to be displayed in a div control which already exists and add those images to that div

As of now I can display one image using as shown below:

```
Preview.ImageUrl = "~/DownloadImages/" & Session("tempDir").ToString & "/" & filename
```

I would like to know the better solutions!

Here is how the images are generated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#<%=uploader.ClientId%>").plupload({
                runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
                url: 'Default.aspx',
                max_file_size: '10mb',
                max_file_count: 21,
                chunk_size: '1mb',
                unique_names: true,
                rename: true,
                dragdrop: true,
                filters: [
            { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
            { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
        ],

                flash_swf_url: 'js/plupload.flash.swf',


                silverlight_xap_url: 'js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
            });



            $('form').submit(function (e) {
                var uploader = $('#<%=uploader.ClientId%>').plupload('getUploader');


                if (uploader.files.length > 0) {

                    uploader.bind('StateChanged', function () {
                        if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                            $('form')[0].submit();
                        }
                    });

                    uploader.start();
                }
                else
                //alert('You must at least upload one file.');

                    return false;
            });



            var uploader = $('#<%=uploader.ClientId%>').plupload('getUploader');
            uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {

                var i = up.files.length,
                maxCountError = false;

                plupload.each(files, function (file) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        up.start();
                    }, 100);



                    if (uploader.settings.max_file_count && i >= uploader.settings.max_file_count) {
                        $.msgBox({
                            title: "Info",
                            content: "Max Files Reached.",
                            type: "info",
                            showButtons: true,
                            opacity: 0.1,
                            autoClose: false
                        });
                        uploader.removeFile(up.files[i - 1]);
                    } else {

                    }
                });

            });


            var uploader = $('#<%=uploader.ClientId%>').plupload('getUploader');
            uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, res) {

                $('#<%=thumbs.ClientId%>').append("<div id=" + file.id + "><a href='Uploads/" + document.getElementById("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "' rel='group1'><img class='clickImage' src='Uploads/" + document.getElementById("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "' width='75' height='50' data-full='Uploads/" + document.getElementById("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "'/></div>");
                if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                    showStickySuccessToast();
                }

            });
        });




        function randomString(length) {
            var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

            if (!length) {
                length = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            }

            var str = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                str += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
            }
            return str;
        }
    </script>
```

If I know how many Images users can add then it's easy but It's hard to say thats the main issue.

Comment: You need to add more details; what you said is confusing: e.g. do you want all images displayed at once, or one at a time (where you'd somehow be switching; how? button click?).

Comment: @Hari-Sorry if it's confusing you!I need to add all Images from existing folder and I need to display them.And Not one at a time all at once.

Comment: In that case, the answer that @H27studio provided should work for you. Except maybe you could use Panel control instead of the div#existingDiv, if that's easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Literal or Image Controls and add them on a Panel (or even a div if you add runat="server" to it on the aspx file)

```
<div id="existingDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

I prefer Image controls... something like this: (this is a very simple example of course)

```
foreach(string imageURL in urlsList)
{
    var img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    img.ImageUrl=imageURL;
img.Width = 200;
img.Height = 100;
this.div1.Controls.Add(img);
}
```

EDIT:
Inside urlsList i load the urls like so: (VB)

```
Dim urls As New List(Of String) 'I dont know if you need another parenthesis here on VB...
urls.Add("imageurl1")
urls.Add("imageurl2")
```

Comment: @H27studio-Thanks for your reply.When I convert this sample to VB it shows me error at urlsList what do I need to replace that?

Comment: For VB also is:  new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image() With { .ImageUrl = imageURL}

Comment: @DotNetter _What does the error say_?  Error messages are not magic incantations.

Comment: Thats one change, and in urlsList you have to create an array or a List(of String) and add inside the Urls of the images. ;-)

Comment: @SLaks-The error is not very specific as it shows as generate method stub for my aspx page

Comment: @H27Studio-The main problem is I cannot create an array and give the URL's of those Images as they are generated dynamically.

Comment: If you have the images on a folder, you can make a list of the URls

Comment: @H27Studio and SLaks-I have edited my question how the images are added dynamically.

Comment: @H27-It worked well but the one thing is If it is more than 40+ is there any other better way please let me know as for all those images I need to add manually url list.And how do I set the height and width for those images.

Comment: I updated the image creation, there are width and height properties.

Comment: @H27Studio-Thanks for the edit and one last question when I do this it is adding twice the same image.

Comment: Does it add them twice on each page refresh? If so, add a Me.PanelID.Controls.Clear() before adding the images again.

Comment: Sorry I have done mistake and now it got working.Thank you so much you have really saved a bunch of time for me :)Cheers